# Enforced CPU architecture in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly, sse

In Visual Studio (I'm using 2010) you can specify **CPU architecture** using e.g. **/arch:SSE2**.

Looking at the resulting assembly code for a simple **sin(x)** calculation it indeed uses SSE, but the compiler has also inserted a run-time check with a **fallback** to use **x87** instructions in case the CPU does not support SSE. This run-time check may be executed very frequently and *degrade the performance*.

Is there any flag or settings to **omit this run-time check** and have the program crash with "illegal instruction" instead?

Comment: What happens if you compile with the `/Oi` option set (use intrinsics). More on that option here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f99tchzc.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but it still performs the run-time check. The global variable being checked is named ___use_sse2_mathfcns. I tried googling for it, but unfortunately there are few hits.

Comment: Perhaps that's because **sin()** is part of CRT, so compilation options of your project does not affect it. I suppose you'll see SSE implementation even if you set `/arch:IA32`.

Comment: @stgatilov that was one reason I suggested intrinsics. If the intrinsic exists it doesn't need the builtin one from the CRT. And yes, you'd see the SSE check done in IA32 code. It is impractical to have a CRT built for every code generation option combination so it makes sense that they'd do run time checks instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stgatilov suspected, the implementation of `sin` is part of the C runtime library and isn't directly affected by the `/arch` option. However, there are a couple of options that you can use that will force the use of specific implementation.

If you use the `/fp:fast` option with the `/arch:SSE2` flag then an SSE specific C runtime library function will be used. The downside of using the `/fp:fast` is that generated floating point code becomes less conformant for the entire translation unit, not just for the call to `sin`.

The other, more targeted, alternative is `/Qfast_transcendentals`, this will cause the compiler to always inline the x87 `fsin` instruction. This has disadvantage of making `sin` less conformant, but only `sin` and any other transcendental function with an x87 equivalent instruction you might be using. One notable limitation of the `fsin` instruction is that it only works with a source operand in the range of −2^63 to +2^63.

I should point out however the "runtime check" for SSE2 CPU support has an insignificant performance impact. It's just a compare and branch. Since the compare will always resolve the same way the branch will always be correctly predicted, and so will only cost a few cycles. Compared to the cost of computing sine, that's nothing.

Finally another possible solution is to upgrade your compiler. By default Visual Studio 2015 calls an SSE2 specific implementation of `sin` when using `/arch:SSE2` (which is also the default).

Comment: You beat me to it. I was using VS2015 and I got different behaviour. Loaded a virtual machine I had VS2010 and I can confirm what you observed in that environment (and what the OP saw). As well on my VS2015 I was able to use `/fp:precise` and simply enable intrinsics (/Od) and it generated an SSE2 specific call to `__libm_sse2_sin_precise` (different behaviour compared to VS2010)

Comment: My understanding is that the x87 `fsin` instruction is slower than computing `sin` from a Taylor Series using SSE2

Comment: @MichaelPetch Could be, I never tested actual performance, just whether the SSE2 runtime check was still present. Hopefully the original poster will check to see what alternative actually gives him the best performance  without compromising the results.

Comment: Thanks, it is great to have confirmation that VS2015 solves the problem, I will consider upgrading. While it is true that the branch prediction will love this run-time check, there is also a memory access to the global variable. This access will have a much more significant performance impact, especially in my case where I'm working with huge amounts of RAM and suffering an incredible amount of cache misses.